# How do I get the sys_language_uid with extbase

Tags: extbase, typo3-9.x

In TYPO3 9.5 is only $GLOBALS['TSFE']->sys_language_isocode available. How do I get the numeric sys_languagae_uid in my controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the new `Context` singleton for this:

```php
$context = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(Context::class);
return (int)$context->getPropertyFromAspect('language', 'id');
```

This will return the numerical "sys_language_uid". When you look into the docblock of the Context class (see `public/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Context/Context.php`, there is also a list of possible aspects you may use. There also is a [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/9.5/en-us/ApiOverview/Context/Index.html) available.